# React - Return an object to pass through props

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to react. I need to use the values from an object to pass through on props.. So I have object that I would like to use something like this code. ..

```
// myTemplates.js
export const getTemplate = () => {
    return {
        "path": require("../client/assets/images/Rectangle.png")
    }
}
```

I need to use the path here in the image src

```
// something like..
var template = ?
<TemplateCard

    cardComponent={ <img src={ "" } /> }
>
</TemplateCard>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be easy like this:

```js
import getTemplate from './myTemplate.js'

export default function TemplateCard () { 

  var template = getTemplate();
  return (<TemplateCard

    cardComponent={ <img src={ template.path } /> }
  >
  </TemplateCard>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: I am getting - Uncaught ReferenceError: template is not defined But only when i add it to the src cardComponent={ <img src={ template.path} /> }

Comment: define template in the scope of the render function. I will edit my answer.